Torn between choosing a simple embodiment and a complex embodiment for the detailed specification
I'm in the process of writing the detailed specification for a patent draft.
I have two embodiments, where embodiment A is a simpler one and embodiment B is a more complex one. In real-life practice, it may well be that embodiment B is the one that gets implemented. However, that is not to say that embodiment A won't work. It is just that embodiment B might have a greater commercial payoff because it covers more of the market. However, as of now, I am really not sure how to fill in some of the details for embodiment B, as it is more complex (as I have mentioned).
So, should I describe embodiment A (where I am able to specify the details with more confidence) and leave it at that or should I describe embodiment B (and fill in the details as well as I can and hope for the best)?
The single set of patent claims themselves will cover both cases, so I'm not so worried about the claims themselves. I am more concerned about the detailed specification.

Use both. There is no reason not to have more than one embodiment detailed. And a third if possible.
One successful inventor advised me to think about a cheap, less effective version that might provide 80% of the customer benefit and be sure to cover that embodiment.
You say you are not sure how to fully describe the complex version. As long as all the claimed concepts are yours, you can hire expertise to finish details beyond your background.

I'm concerned about making a mistake in the complex version. Would this invalidate the patent? I get your point about hiring expertise. I might have to do that.

Moreover, going beyond technical implementation, this patent is something really novel. It incorporates a social element where it is hard to predict how things will pan out in the complex version of it. I'm afraid I can't depend on external technical help for that part, as I am supposed to be the expert on it! If I can't predict the end result, it wouldn't be feasible to ask someone else. That's the main reason behind my lack of confidence.

@Joebevo You are an expert on your invention. You are not an expert on writing and prosecuting patent applications. If you really believe you can make money with this invention, do yourself a favor and hire a patent attorney.

@Joebevo - your specification needs to teach someone of ordinary skill in the field how to make and use your invention, as claimed.  If you can't do this you may not have made a patentable invention of the complex version. If not be sure the claims do not encompass the complicated version that you can't enable. You can get expertise from others, even inventive expertise from others. But then they would need to be listed as inventors. You can have a proper assignment of any rights this might give them to you personally or to a company or partnership.
